# Is this SOA record required?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm migrating a domain name from an ASP host to Enom.com.  Using my hosting provider's nameservers, the DNS configuration is below.  I'd like to switch to using Enom's servers, but I'm unsure what to do with the SOA record.  I've never seen this on a domain name before...

Is it necessary?
I've never seen this on any domain name before... is there something about a Windows hosting environment that requires it?
Enom doesn't seem to have a way when editing host records to modify/create SOA records...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => MyDomain.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 5
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 64.79.167.6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => MyDomain.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 5
            [type] => MX
            [pri] => 10
            [target] => sm08.internetmailserver.net
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [host] => MyDomain.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 5
            [type] => SOA
            [mname] => ns1.discountasp.net
            [rname] => hostmaster.discountasp.net
            [serial] => 1387224509
            [refresh] => 16384
            [retry] => 2048
            [expire] => 1048576
            [minimum-ttl] => 2560
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [host] => MyDomain.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 5
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns3.discountasp.net
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [host] => MyDomain.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 5
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns2.discountasp.net
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [host] => MyDomain.net
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 5
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns1.discountasp.net
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOA states for Start Of Authority and is kept at the top of the zone record files. This record is responsible for telling the DNS environment which is the NS server and who is the person responsible for some domain.  It is formatted as:

```
example.com.  ns1.example.com. dnsadmin.example.com.
```

Usually, at hosters, this record is automatically filled, so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

The second you create a new zone at enom.com (or any other hosting provider), a new SOA record will be created automatically. The SOA contains the FQDN of the primary NS, and hostmaster contact address among other details.

No need to copy it from your existing NS, if you're trying to recreate the zone at a new provider.